# Unknown directive '#' at line 49 of /etc/asterisk/chan_dahdi.conf

Tags: asterisk

To configure dadhi on asterisk I am following [this](http://www.saruman.biz/wiki/index.php/Installing_and_configuring_DAHDI) blog. I get the above error for line

```
[channels]
  # include /etc/asterisk/dahdi-channels.conf
```

What am I doing wrong here, I should not be getting a WARNING for #include configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Damn, silly mistake. I just removed the space's in the `# include` and the WARNING disappeared.

I now have

```
#include /etc/asterisk/dahdi-channels.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this error because someone put a comment in our `/etc/asterisk/asterisk.conf`, but preceded it with a `#`.

I found some documentation links explaining that [single-line comments](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Comments+on+a+Single+Line) should be preceded by `;`, while `#` is used for [Constructs](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Using+The+include%2C+tryinclude+and+exec+Constructs), like `#include` or `#exec`.